# Bug in mapStateToProps() from fetching json object in Redux

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, fetch, state

I'm trying to fetch data from my Express server in Redux, and mapping over the object to just use one array, called "vitamins". This is the json object.

```
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  vitamins: [
     {
        name: "Vitamin B2"
     }
  ],
  minerals: [
    {
       name: "Zinc"
    }
  ]});
 });
```

This is my action.js, where I'm creating the function fetchVitamins() to just fetch micros.vitamins.

```
export function fetchVitamins() {
return dispatch => {
  return fetch("/users")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(micros => {
       dispatch(fetchVitaminsSuccess(micros.vitamins));
       return micros.vitamins;
    })
  };
}

export const FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS';

export const fetchVitaminsSuccess = vitamins => ({
  type: FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS,
  payload: { vitamins }
});
```

This is my reducers.js

```
 const initialState = {
   micros: [],
 };

function vitaminReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS:
   return {
     ...state,
     micros: action.payload.vitamins
   };
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

This is my React component Vitamins.js where I'm importing fetchVitamins() and trying to pass the names of each vitamins to a menu dropdown in an option tag.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.dispatch(fetchVitamins());
}

renderData() {
   const { vitamins } = this.state.micros;
   return vitamins.map((micro, index) => {
      return (
        <option value={micro.value} key={index}>{micro.name}</option>
      )
   })
 } 

 render() {
   return (
      <select value={this.props.value}>
        {this.renderData()}
      </select>
   )
 }

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    micros: state.micros.vitamins,
 });
```

Right now when it renders, I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'vitamins' of undefined", highlighting over "micros: state.micros.vitamins,".

Am I calling and setting state correctly? If I set my initialState to micros: [], then setting the state to "state.micros.vitamins" should work, I thought.

Comment: when you look at your network tab in chrome, do you even see the information being passed back? And you are hitting route `/users` while you express is serving `/`. I would recommend use the redux extension to see if things are changing

Comment: @Leogoesger No, nothing is coming back in my Networks tab or in the Redux store. It was working fine with express serving `/` when I was fetching in just React and setting it to my localState, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: You made a typo in your mapStateToProps. Instead of `micros: state.micros.vitamins` there might be `micros: state.micros`

Comment: Same in the reducer, should be `action.payload` rather than `action.payload.vitamins`

Comment: @coockoo , @Barazu I did both, and now I get this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'micros' of null" on my `renderData()` function for the line `const { vitamins } = this.state.micros;`

Comment: Also, you make fetch to `/users` instead of `/` as in your express server. I'd recommend you to double check what data and where you fetch it. And in what format you keep it in your store. Clearly, the issue is with it. Also, haven't you forget to `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)` using redux [connect](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)?

Comment: @coockoo I deleted the renderData() function and just kept `componentDidMount() {  this.props.fetchVitamins();`, installed redux-thunk and applied it in `index.js`, and that worked. I got back `users` in my Networks tab and console.logged the object being fetched and got it back, too.  I have `export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchVitamins })(Vitamins);` too. But when i add back `renderData()` function, I get the same error, and `users` doesn't show up in my Network tab anymore.

Comment: Be sure you have your initialState in the same format as your data from the server. (In your case, be sure that initial state contains `micros` object that has `vitamins` array in it).

Comment: I have `.then(micros => dispatch(fetchVitaminsSuccess(micros.vitamins)); return micros.vitamins; })` in my fetch function, and `const initialState = { micros: [ ],}` in my reducers. In my `vitaminReducer()` function in reducers, i have it `case: FETCH_VITAMINS_SUCCESS: return { ...state.vitamins, micros: action.payload`

Answer (score 0):

because of you get the server data n vitamins objects so that data should be in vitamins:[], in that Format so that why state.macros.vitamins work.